# How to catch events on form from class library (.dll)?

Tags: vb.net

How to get events from dll?

Yeah, but I don't know how use addhandler in a function. I'm stuck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka(VS.80).aspx) statement or declare a `Sub` with the [`Handles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y(VS.80).aspx) keyword, like you would for any event.

Are you sure your DLL exposes events, though?  You'll have to look at the documentation for your DLL.  In the worst case, you might need to use a tool like [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to examine the DLL and see what events are declared in the code.